# Swapping rows with VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, rows, swap

I would like to swap specific rows based on condition.
My workbooks contain sets of multiple row pairs:

row 1:

row 2: entry1; value1

row 3: entry2; value2

row 4:

row 5: entry3; value3

row 6: entry4; value4

row 7:
...

I would like to swap rows in a pair of entries if a certain condition is true. For example if value 2 is larger than value 1 (first pair of entries), swap rows 2 and 3. Continue to the next pair. If value 4 is larger than value 3 (second pair of entries), swap row 5 and 6. If value 4 is not larger that value 3 leave the pair as it is. I already figured out how to swap two rows manually, but since i have a large list with multiple pairs of rows I would like to automate the process. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope below code will help to compare and swap/move the column if the 2nd value is greater than 1st value

Below are the image of the excel sheet

Before Running the code

[image: Before running the code]

After running the code

[image: After Running the code]

CODE:

```
Public Working_Sheet As Worksheet
Public FirstRow As Integer
Public LastRow As Integer
Public Comp_No1, Comp_No2


Sub Button1_Click()
'Setting the worksheet where data avaliable
Set Working_Sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Marking the first row number
FirstRow = 1

'Marking the last row number
LastRow = Working_Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox (LastRow)


'Looping throught all the rows
For i = 2 To LastRow


'Ass the first compare row and the +1 for second compare
Comp_No1 = i
Comp_No2 = i + 1

'Checking the Column A with the number to make sure its not empty
If Working_Sheet.Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then

'MsgBox (Working_Sheet.Range("B" & Comp_No1).Value)
'MsgBox (Working_Sheet.Range("B" & Comp_No2).Value)

'Checking if the B value of Second entry is less than B Value of the is Entry
If Working_Sheet.Range("B" & Comp_No1).Value < Working_Sheet.Range("B" & Comp_No2).Value Then
'Cutting 2nd row
Rows(i + 1).Cut
'Moving or inserting the cutted row to pervious row
Rows(i).Insert
End If


End If

'inc the I value +2 for next row
i = i + 2


Next

End Sub
```